# scikit learn: elastic net approaching ridge

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

So elastic net is supposed to be a hybrid between ridge regression (L2 regularization) and lasso (L1 regularization). However, it seems that even if l1_ratio is 0 I don't get the same result as ridge. I know ridge using gradient descent and elastic net uses coordinate descent, but the optima should be the same, no? Moreover, I've found that elasticnet often throws ConvergenceWarnings for no obvious reason, while lasso and ridge don't. Here's a snippet:

```python
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.linear_model import ElasticNet, Ridge, Lasso
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

data = load_boston()
X, y = shuffle(data.data, data.target, random_state=42)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=43)
alpha = 1

en = ElasticNet(alpha=alpha, l1_ratio=0)
en.fit(X_train, y_train)
print('en train score: ', en.score(X_train, y_train))

rr = Ridge(alpha=alpha)
rr.fit(X_train, y_train)
print('rr train score: ', rr.score(X_train, y_train))

lr = Lasso(alpha=alpha)
lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
print('lr train score: ', lr.score(X_train, y_train))
print('---')
print('en test score: ', en.score(X_test, y_test))
print('rr test score: ', rr.score(X_test, y_test))
print('lr test score: ', lr.score(X_test, y_test))
print('---')
print('en coef: ', en.coef_)
print('rr coef: ', rr.coef_)
print('lr coef: ', lr.coef_)
```

Even though l1_ratio is 0, the train and test scores of elastic net are close to the lasso scores (and not ridge as you would expect). Moreover, elastic net seems to throw a ConvergenceWarning, even if I increase max_iter (even up to 1000000 there seems to be no effect) and tol (0.1 still throws an error, but 0.2 doesn't). Increasing alpha (as the warning suggests) also has no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just read the docs. Then you will find out that none of these is using Gradient-descent and more important:

[Ridge](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#ridge-regression)

[image]

[image]

[Elastic Net](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#elastic-net)

[image]
[image]

which shows, when substituting `a=1, p=0`, that:

- ElasticNet has one more sample-dependent factor on top of the loss not found in Ridge
- ElasticNet has one more `1/2` factor in the l2-term

Why different models? Probably because sklearn follows the canonical/original [R-based implementation glmnet](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/glmnet.pdf).

Furthermore i would not be surprised to see numerical-issues when doing mixed-norm optimization while i'm forcing a non-mixed norm like l1=0, especially when there are specialized solvers for both non-mixed optimization-problems.

Luckily, sklearn even [has to say something about it](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.ElasticNet.html#sklearn-linear-model-elasticnet):

> Currently, l1_ratio <= 0.01 is not reliable, unless you supply your own sequence of alpha.

Comment: Your post implies that when l1_ratio=0, then the elastic net alpha should be divided by n_samples to match the same optimization problem as ridge. This was indeed the case, and in that case the elastic net and ridge lead to the same coefficients.

However, there is still a ConvergenceWarning for the elastic net. I don't see why: the coefficients are the same as ridge (so they converged), and ridge doesn't give this warning. You also mentioned that l1_ratio <= 0.01 is not reliable unless you supply your own sequence (?) of alpha.

Comment: And I did supply my own alpha (you can only pass one if you don't use ElasticnetCV), but it still seems like something doesn't work as intended with l1_ratio = 0. From the documentation of ElasticnetCV I see that they suggest using a l1_ratio sequence of [.1, .5, .7, .9, .95, .99, 1], clearly avoiding l1_ratio=0...

Comment: Different optimizers, different assumptions, different numerical-issues. Using ```l1_ratio=0``` is covered by special optimizers (the optimization problem is way more easy), so using elasticnet is not really recommended.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the answer by @sascha, one can match the results between the two models:

```python
import sklearn
print(sklearn.__version__)

from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge, ElasticNet
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston

dataset = load_boston()
X = dataset.data
y = dataset.target

f = Ridge(alpha=1, 
          fit_intercept=True, normalize=False, 
          copy_X=True, max_iter=1000, tol=1e-4, random_state=42, 
          solver='auto')
g = ElasticNet(alpha=1/X.shape[0], l1_ratio=1e-16, 
               fit_intercept=True, normalize=False, 
               copy_X=True, max_iter=1000, tol=1e-4, random_state=42, 
               precompute=False, warm_start=False, 
               positive=False, selection='cyclic')

f.fit(X, y)
g.fit(X, y)

print(abs(f.coef_ - g.coef_) / abs(f.coef_))
```

Output:

```
0.19.2
[1.19195623e-14 1.17076625e-15 3.25973465e-13 1.61694280e-14
 4.77274767e-15 4.15332538e-15 6.15640568e-14 1.61772832e-15
 4.56125088e-14 5.44320605e-14 8.99189018e-15 2.31213025e-15
 3.74181954e-15]
```

Comment: To generalize further for any non-zero alpha=a, Ridge(alpha=a, ...) and ElasticNet(alpha=a/X.shape[0], ...)